# Should I put in my resume StackOverflow profile that has reputation build by ASKING QUESTIONS?

Tags: resume, reputation

I see numerous problems at the moment with my SO reputation and current career goals. There are some career advice to put SO account in a resume but I feel like my SO account would not be very attractive to employers:

- Current 4k reputation was built by asking questions (318 questions vs 8 answers)
- It is not in 10k league
- Being a member of SO for 6 years but the rate between questions and answers has not changed.
- The top rated question is a C# beginner question. I am heading toward the Java ecosystem.

Comment: This has been asked a bazillion times already on various SE sites.

Comment: In response to the update, how about this: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=should+i+put+my+stack+overflow+reputation+on+my+resume

Comment: It is not easy to build real life reputation by asking questions, but you can definitely do that by asking the right and important questions. Just my two cents generally.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the first contact hiring people I know would have no idea what stack exchange is, so it would be totally irrelevant and it's not very useful to put irrelevant stuff in a resume and might get you filtered out before you even get to an interview.

In terms of sculpting your SO profile for the purpose of getting a job, I would think that accepted answers and high rep would be preferable to asking a lot of questions if indeed you thought it necessary to mention at all.

Comment: I don't think that answering lots of questions is necessarily good as well.  High internet forum use can be seen as an indication that you'd rather surf the internet instead of working on your projects...

Comment: @Pete Indeed, this is all very much subject to interpretation (That's why I voted to close the question as *primarily opinion-based*).

Comment: @Pete I don't think it's open to interpretation, it seems axiomatic that someone who has the answers is preferable to someone who doesn't. If the OP really wants to advertise in that manner. My first paragraph addresses whether he/she should.